# Javascript Script inside HTML is not executing with Angular 12

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Problem: I am trying to hide my navigation bar on scroll-down and show it on scroll-up. I placed my JavaScript to do this inside my `HTML` body at the bottom of the page, but it does not work. Any help is appreciated.

**HTML(mainpage.component.html):**

```
<body>
    <div class="flex" id="outercontainer">    
        <nav id="navbar">
            <a href="#" class="brand">Brand Name</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#blogs">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div>
        //content
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if(scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
            navbar.style.top="-80px";
        } else{
            navbar.style.top="0";
        }
        lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    })    
</script>
</body>
```

CSS (mainpage.component.scss)

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif ;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background:#607d8b;
    padding: 0 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.brand{
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;

}
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f6edd9;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;

    #sidebar{
    width: 10vw;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    max-width: 80px;
    min-width: 30px;
    }

}

#banner{
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;

    #nameimagecontainer{
    width: 60%;
    }

    #selfphotocontainer{
    width: 30%;
    }
}

#contentcontainer{
    font-size: 30px;
}
#getintouchbutton{
    font-style: normal;
}
#mainpagecontainer{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;  

    #workcontainer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: green;
    }
    #servicescontainer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: red;
    }    

    #actioncontainer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: purple;
    }
    #contactcontainer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;    
        background-color: orange;
    }

}
```

So far, my script does nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to [this article](https://blog.davidjs.com/2018/09/insert-script-tags-in-angular-components/) on how to add scripts to the code.

However, I would not recommend to do this. Angular removes all script tags from the code, and it is uncommon practice to add scripts this way.

Much better approach would be to move the code in "script" tag into Your `mainpage.component.ts` into `ngOnInit` method.

Answer (score 0):

add your scripts code inside your mainpage.component.ts

example://

```
constructor(){
   var lastScrollTop = 0;
        navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if(scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
            navbar.style.top="-80px";
        } else{
            navbar.style.top="0";
        }
        lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    })    
}
```

// or you can use lifecycle hook here

```
ngOnInit(){
   var lastScrollTop = 0;
            navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
        window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
            var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            if(scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
                navbar.style.top="-80px";
            } else{
                navbar.style.top="0";
            }
            lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
        }) 
}
```

still i would recommend Renderer2 or DOCUMENT injection token, you can read about them in angular documentation

Comment: I tried the first method and added the constructor after ngOnInit() and it gives me an error underlining the first navbar variable saying "Cannot find name navbar" and also the same error under 'navbar'.style.top

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document:Document){
}

@HostListener('scroll',['$event'])
onScrollHandler(e:Event){
let lastScrollTop = 0;
 const navbar = this.document.getElementById("navbar"); // you can use viewchild,renderer2 also

const scrollTop = this.document.defaultView.pageYOffset || this.document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            if(scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
                navbar.style.top="-80px";
            } else{
                navbar.style.top="0";
            }
            lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
}

ngOnInit(){

        }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your code inside the mainpage.component.ts file

Answer (score 0):

The [blog](https://blog.davidjs.com/2018/09/insert-script-tags-in-angular-components/) from [Pavlo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69388999/13890583) worked for me.

In your case, first, you'd need to add a `.js` file to your project's `assets` folder which is present by default in Angular:

**yourcode.js (assets/yourcode.js):**

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if(scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
        navbar.style.top="-80px";
    } else{
        navbar.style.top="0";
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
})
```

Now your HTML file would look like this (you don't need to add script you'll see why):

**HTML (mainpage.component.html):**

```
<body>
<div class="flex" id="outercontainer">    
    <nav id="navbar">
        <a href="#" class="brand">Brand Name</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blogs">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
    //content
    </div>
</body>
```

Next you'd need to modify the component's typescript. Here you create a script DOM element, set the src  and attach it to the DOM via renderer service, which is why you don't need the script tag inside the HTML file anymore.

You just have to add the path to your file which would be something like `../assets/yourcode.js`. The code would look like this:

**mainpage.component.ts**

```
// 1. import dependencies
import { Renderer2, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';


// 2. pass then in constructor
constructor(
    private renderer2: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document
  ) {
  }


// 3. call them in ngOnInit
ngOnInit() {
   const s = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
   s.type = 'text/javascript';
   // the path to your script inside the assets folder '../assets/yourcode.js'
   s.src = 'https://path/to/your/script';
   s.text = ``;
   this.renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, s);
}
```